# How do you implement overloaded interface methods which use different generics in java?

Tags: java, generics, interface, overloading

This is my interface:

```
public interface Graph<V, E> {

    Vertex<V> insert(V v);

    Edge<E> insert(Vertex<V> from, Vertex<V> to, E e)
        throws PositionException, InsertionException;
}
```

This is position interface:

```
public interface Position<T> {
    T get();

    void put(T t);
}
```

This is my class which implements Graph:

```
public class SparseGraph<V, E> implements Graph<V, E> {
    private class Vertex<V> implements Position<V> {
        V data;
        public V get() {
            return this.data;
        }

        public void put(V v) {
            this.data = v;
        }
    }

    private class Edge<E> implements Position<E> {
        E identifier;
        Vertex<V> from;
        Vertex<V> to;

        @Override
        public E get() {
            return this.identifier;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(E e) {
            this.identifier = e;
        }
    }

    public Vertex<V> insert(V v) {
        return null;
    }

    public Edge<E> insert(Vertex<V> from, Vertex<V> to, E e)
        throws PositionException, InsertionException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Everything looks right to me but when I compile, I get this:

```
SparseGraph.java:36: error: insert(V#1) in SparseGraph cannot implement 
insert(V#2) in Graph
public Vertex<V> insert(V v) {
                 ^
return type SparseGraph<V#1,E>.Vertex<V#1> is not compatible with 
Vertex<V#1>
where V#1,E,V#2 are type-variables:
V#1 extends Object declared in class SparseGraph
E extends Object declared in class SparseGraph
V#2 extends Object declared in interface Graph
```

I tried searching this problem up, but the only similar question I found had no answer due to lack of code posted. What is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: _insert_ should return just _V_, not _Vertex<V>_

Comment: Where is code for position? I think you will be getting error in interface too as it will be unable to find Vertex and Edge. Both are private class in SparseGraph class so will not be visible outside

Comment: `private class Vertex<V>` is a different Vertex class than the one referred to by the Position interface.